# Firebase Sign-in with email after google sign-in has error : The password is invalid or the user does not have a password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase Authentication service for my iOS application. I want to sign-in app using by email or google sign-in provider. I applied [firebase instractions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin).

I could login with email and password. Then I can sign-out with Firebase signout method:

`Auth.auth().signOut()`

Later, I could signing and signout with google successfully. When I re-authenticaite with email and password, this message is returned:

> The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.

and I couldn't sign-in with email.

On Firebase console, the users account symbol change from  mail [image: mail] to Google [image: Google]. So, I could signing with only Google sign-in provider, not email.

I couldn't solve this problem. What is my wrong? Below, there are my code parts.

In addition that, when I reset password on firebase console, I could sign-in with two of them. And two image are appeared on console together: [image] 
How can I solve this trouble?

Thanks!

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        log.debug("Error Google Sign-in: \(error)")
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in

        if let error = error {
            log.error(error)
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
    }
}
```

This is the logout button action:

```
@IBAction func logout_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    } catch let error {
        log.error(error.localizedDescription)

    }
    log.info("After  logout current user: \(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser))")
}
```

Comment: Are you using same gmail account for google and email authentication?

Comment: Are they same users ? if yes, you can link that accounts together.. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking)

Comment: @TheTiger yes, same email account.

Comment: @Ozan where should I use "user.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential)" command? I couldn't got it. Could you give an example code?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270030/1411004

Answer (score 0):

This happens only for email&password accounts that have **not** been verified as mentioned here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/122#issuecomment-291528845